# Does the column generation sub-problem involve solving an IP? (high-level question, and also specific paper)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I understand column generation at its basic level, thanks to these two resources:

1. https://optimization.cbe.cornell.edu/index.php?title=Column_generation_algorithms
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O918V86Grhc

Both of these resources solve the same problem (canonical cutting stock problem), and the same sub-problem with different parameters.
However, in both of the above, the way they describe the column generation sub-problem (AKA "pricing sub-problem"), it involves solving the knapsack problem. (go to 20 minutes into resource 2, and scroll down to "In our example,...." in resource 1).

The knapsack problem is also an IP.  Are we solving the relaxation of this problem?  Either way, how is this column generation saving us any computation time if we still need to solve an IP?

To be more specific, [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037722171730231X) claims that it is easier to solve the column generation subproblem by "allowing non-elementary routes" (see section 2.3, 4th paragraph and the following paragraphs).  But this doesn't make sense to me if we are solving an integer program at each column generation sub-problem.  Can someone help me understand this?

Related question: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/9325/

Comment: Presumably, said knapsack problem would be solved via dynamic programming.

Comment: Then why not solve the original master problem via dynamic programming?